# Deriving the difference equation of the filter

Tags: filters, filter-design

Here I have a diagram (at the bottom) and I am trying to create a difference equation for the filter.

I've been using practice examples to try figure this one out however I am unable to produce a complete difference equation.

For example:

```
      x[n] ---| A |---+---| B |--- y[n]
             z^-1  |   z^-1
                   +---| C |
                       z^-1
```

where $x \left[ n \right]$ is the input signal, $y \left[ n \right]$ is the output signal, and $A$, $B$, and $C$ are blocks with transfer functions:

$A$: $H_{1} \left( z \right) = \frac{1 + 2 z^{-1} + z^{-2}}{1 + 0.5 z^{-1}}$
$B$: $H_{2} \left( z \right) = \frac{1 - z^{-1}}{1 - 0.8 z^{-1}}$
$C$: $H_{3} \left( z \right) = \frac{1 + z^{-1}}{1 + 0.9 z^{-1} + 0.2 z^{-2}}$

Block $A$: input = $x \left[ n \right]$, output = $a \left[ n \right]$
Block $B$: input = $a \left[ n - 1 \right]$, output = $b \left[ n \right]$
Block $C$: input = $b \left[ n - 1 \right]$, output = $y \left[ n \right]$\

Step 3: Write down the equations for each block.\

Block $A$: $a \left[ n \right] = H_{1} \left( z \right) x \left[ n \right] + 0.5 a \left[ n - 1 \right] - 0.5 a \left[ n - 2 \right] - H_{1} \left( z \right) z^{-1} x \left[ n \right]$
Block $B$: $b \left[ n \right] = H_{2} \left( z \right) a \left[ n - 1 \right] + 0.8 b\left[ n - 1 \right] - H_{2} \left( z \right) z^{-1} a \left[ n - 1 \right]$
Block $C$: $y \left[ n \right] = H_{3} \left( z \right) b \left[ n - 1 \right] - 0.9 y \left[ n - 1 \right] - 0.2 y \left[ n - 2 \right] + H_{3} \left( z \right) z^{-1} b \left[ n - 1 \right]$

Step 4: Combine the equations for all blocks to obtain the overall system equation.

Substituting the equation for $a \left[ n \right]$ into the equation for $b \left[ n \right]$, and the equation for $b \left[ n \right]$ into the equation for $y \left[ n \right]$, we get:

$y \left[ n \right] = H_{3} \left( z \right) H_{2} \left( z \right) \left( H_{1} \left( z \right) x \left[ n \right] + 0.5 H_{1} \left( z \right) z^{-1} x \left[ n - 1 \right] - 0.5 H_{1} \left( z \right) z^{-2} x \left[ n - 2 \right] - 0.8 a \left[ n - 1 \right] + H_{2} \left( z \right) z^{-1} a \left[ n - 1 \right] \right) - 0.9 y \left[ n - 1 \right] - 0.2 y \left[ n - 2 \right]$

Step 5: Use the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform to convert the system equation into a difference equation.

**etc.. This is how I would usually approach this type of question; However I can't quite figure this one out. Would someone be able to give me the answer so I can reverse engineer this or at least put me along the right track!**

[image: Second Order Filter]

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic biquad difference equation. No need to go to or from the $\mathcal{Z}$-domain:

$$y[n] = a_0x[n] + a_1x[n-1] + a_2x[n-2] + b_1y[n-1] + b_2y[n-2]$$
usually written with input on one side and output on the other:
$$y[n] - b_1y[n-1] - b_2y[n-2] = a_0x[n] + a_1x[n-1] + a_2x[n-2]$$
The associated transfer function is
$$H(z) = \frac{a_0 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2}}{1 + b_1z^{-1} + b_2z^{-2}}$$